# Перевести строки в столбцы bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Имеется скрипт который делает whois и вытаскивает нужные поля:

```
    for as in $(cat as.txt):
do echo -e $as;
whois -h whois.radb.net -i origin $as > whoisas
fields=`cat whoisas | egrep 'route:|descr:|route6:'  | sed s/route:/'\t\r'/g  | sed s/route6:/'\t\r'/g | sed s/descr:/'\t\r'/g ` 
echo $fields
done>as.csv
```

Но в csv они выгружаются в строках, желательно сделать их в столбцы
[image: Пример того как выгружается whois]

```html
AS20473     
    68.232.171.0/24 173.199.84.0/22
    auto-generated route object for 68.232.171.0/24 auto-generated route object for 173.199.84.0/22
    2001    19f0
AS24453     
    58.137.13.0/24  202.151.40.0/21
    CSLoxinfo route object for Rajabhat chandrakasem    Proxy-registered route object
    2403    4c00
```

На текущий момент выдаётся три строки из которых нужно сделать 3 столбца

Получить нужно csv следующего вида:

```html
AS20473 68.232.171.0/24 auto-generated route object for 68.232.171.0/24
    173.199.84.0/22 auto-generated route object for 173.199.84.0/22
    63.209.33.0/24  auto-generated route object for 63.209.33.0/24
```

```
for as in $(cat as.txt):
do echo -e $as;
fields=whois -h whois.radb.net -i origin $as | egrep 'route:|descr:'  | sed s/route:/'\r'/g |  sed s/descr:/'\$'/g  
echo $fields
done>as.csv
```

В итоге вот такой костыль через $, вроде работает и разделяет как надо, но буду рад более элегантным решениям. Мой sed не хочет есть \t, зато прекрасно обрабатывает \r

Comment: AFAIR стандартных утилит для транспонирования csv нет, а голым bash/sed/awk делать это грязно и нудно, так что на практике я бы обратился к языками перло-питоновой группы...

Comment: В силу специфики работы и используемого по - желательно написать это на bash/sed/awk вне зависимости от того насколько грязно и нудно это будет

Comment: значит, пишите. будут вопросы: задавайте, поможем. удачи!

Comment: Так я задал вопрос, мне надо транспонировать строки в столбцы.

Comment: Алгоритм должен быть такой: отбираете **все** нужные строки (а не как у вас сейчас, по отдельности), соединяете каждые три (или сколько у вас там выйдет в блоке) в одну. удачи!

Comment: У вас в коде три лишних вызова `cat` и `grep`.

Comment: `for as in $(cat as.txt):
do echo -e $as;
whois -h whois.radb.net -i origin $as > whoisas
fields=`cat whoisas | egrep 'route:|descr:|route6:'  | sed s/route:/'\t\r'/g  | sed s/route6:/'\t\r'/g | sed s/descr:/'\t\r'/g ` 
echo $fields
done>as.csv`

Скрипт был перелопачен, осталось понять как выставить разделители по столбцам